# First image from google with specific size and keyword (android)

Tags: json, xml, image, size

I am trying to get an image from Google with the specific keyword and size and set it as a background on android device.

The problem is in getting image with **accurate** size.
First I tried Google Image Search API with the request like this:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0&imgsz=huge

But I can't find if it's possible to get the exact size (not just huge or small). May be there is a way?
Then I tried http request:

https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=kitten&tbs=isz:ex,iszw:160,iszh:300
(Kitten, 160x300)

But it seems too difficult to get an image url (for a beginner like me). I find out that appropriate image url will be hidden after the first appearance of 
`"<a href="http://www.google.ru/imgres?imgurl=...."` and before first "&" sign. But when I tried these links, several of them didn't work.

Well, I could move in that direction, but may be there is an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've found several answers, may be it will help someone.

First,  Google Image Search (depricated) and [Google Custom search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) APIs don't allow image search request with specific dimensions. At least, there is no documented way to do this.

Second, I didn't find a way, how to get exact size, but found how to get images (miniatures) with specific ratio (height/width) with [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) lib.

```
        int width = 140, height = 300;
        String imageName = "kitten";
        String webURL =
                "https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q="
                        + imageName 
                        + "&tbs=isz:ex,iszw:"
                        + width 
                        + ",iszh:" 
                        + height;

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(webURL)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .get();
            Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");

            for (Element el : img) {
                String src = el.absUrl("src");
                System.out.println("src attribute is: " + src);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```